# Hibernate cycle reference

Tags: java, hibernate

I have in my app one one-to-many and one many-to-many relationships:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
  Id       INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Login    VARCHAR(15) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  Password VARCHAR(20)        NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products (
  Id    INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Name  VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  Price DOUBLE             NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS orders (
  Id     INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  UserId INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (UserId) REFERENCES users (Id)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS order_products (
  Order_id   INT,
  Product_id INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (Order_id) REFERENCES orders (Id),
  FOREIGN KEY (Product_id) REFERENCES products (Id)
)
```

Entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "Id", unique = true)
    private int Id;

    @Size(min = 3, max = 15)
    @Column(name = "Login", unique = true)
    private String login;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 5, max = 20)
    @Column(name = "Password")
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Order> orders;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Orders")
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "Id", unique = true)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "UserId")
    private User user;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "order_products", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "Order_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "Product_id")})
    private List<Product> products;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "Id", unique = true)
    private int id;


    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 5, max = 30)
    @Column(name = "Name")
    private String name;


    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "Price")
    private double price;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "products")
    private List<Order> orders;
}
```

And if I try to access, for example, user, it references to orders, and orders then reference to the user and finally I got an java.lang.StackOverflowError.

Comment: "got an error" ??? What ?

Comment: java.lang.StackOverflowError

Comment: Problem not in entities, but in application code

Answer (score 1):

This is happening due to entities being eagerly loaded. You need to load them lazily, meaning that it won't load all of the objects immediately, instead, it will load them on-demand.

You need to replace all the places where you use

```
fetch = FetchType.EAGER
```

with

```
fetch = FetchType.LAZY
```

or just remove `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` since `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` is a default loading mechanism.

Here is a nice tutorial to get better understanding of different types of loading: http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-lazy-eager-loading